# Which of these two front struts is the correct one for a 2002 Subaru Outback?

Tags: suspension, subaru, struts

The wife's car (2002 Subaru Outback) is ready for new struts and I'm trying to determine the correct part set.  TireRack, surprisingly, lists [two different sets of front struts](http://www.tirerack.com/suspension/suspension.jsp?make=KYB&model=GR-2%20Strut&group=GR-2&partNum=334448&autoMake=Subaru&autoModel=Outback%20L.L.%20Bean&autoYear=2002&autoModClar=).  One set is for "models after 6/02 only" and the other is for "models before 5/02 only."

Here's the question: how do I determine which pair I need?

I have the VIN number and [I've confirmed that the vehicle is a 2002](http://www.cars101.com/subaru/vin.html#legacy%20Outback) (thanks VIN) but there's no month information there.  Is there another way to determine which part is necessary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There should be some kind of sticker in the driver's side door jamb that will tell you a more specific date of manufacture.

Comment: Good call - it's a 3/02 car.  By the way, it's on the door itself, not the jamb.  I had to get nearly prone beneath it to read but it's there.